# Where to join threads created in an asynchronous tornado request handler?

Tags: python, multithreading, join, tornado

This one has me a bit baffled.  Fairly new to tornado and threading in python, so I could be completely off the mark with what I'm trying to do here.

Probably best to start with some simplified code:

```
class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

  def perform(self):
     #do something cuz hey, we're in a thread!

  def initialize(self):
    self.thread = None

  @tornado.web.asynchronous
  def post(self):

    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.perform)
    self.thread.start()

    self.write('In the request')
    self.finish()

  def on_connection_close(self):
    logging.info('In on_connection_close()')
    if self.thread:
      logging.info('Joining thread: %s' % (self.thread.name))
      self.thread.join()
```

My problem is that `on_connection_close` is never getting called, requests are getting handled just fine.  Secondly, am I doing something terrible introducing threading in this manner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe `Thread.join()` will block until the thread finishes, probably something you want to avoid. Rather than joining, you can have the thread callback to the handler.

When using threads, be aware that tornado isn't thread-safe, so you can't use any RequestHandler (for example) methods from threads.

This works for me:

```
import functools
import time
import threading
import logging

import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.locale
import tornado.ioloop

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def perform(self, callback):
        #do something cuz hey, we're in a thread!
        time.sleep(5)
        output = 'foo'
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(functools.partial(callback, output))

    def initialize(self):
        self.thread = None

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.perform, args=(self.on_callback,))
        self.thread.start()

        self.write('In the request')
        self.flush()

    def on_callback(self, output):
        logging.info('In on_callback()')
        self.write("Thread output: %s" % output)
        self.finish()

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", Handler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

You can test it with `curl --no-buffer localhost:8888`. Some browsers (Safari) seem to wait for the connection to close before displaying any output, which threw me off for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is similar to what I've done with the exception of removing threads altogether.  I haven't done any extensive testing yet, but I think I'm able to get away with just add_callback() to do my 'work'.  I may switch to your solution though -- will do some fiddling tomorrow.

Comment: That might be just fine–you should only use a thread if your operation will block.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `on_connection_close` is only called only when the client terminates the connection, which may explain your problem.
Regarding threading, I don't know what you want to do, but I can't see why you would want to create a thread in a Tornado request as one of the advantages of Tornado is exactly that you don't have to use threading.
If I were to add a `join` to your example I would put it just before `self.finish()`, however, you can probably just omit it... that will depend on what you want to do with the thread, but remember that Tornado is single-threaded and the whole process will block if the thread is not finished by the time `join()` comes.

Comment: I think you're right re: when on_connection_close called.  Been doing some experimentation and it also seems to vary a bit whether ioloop is using epoll or select().  Currently wondering if I should do the join() in a callback I attach via add_callback().

As per threads, I'm using them to perform a bit of work in a 'fire and forget' way.  Basically, I'd like to accept the request, send back some ACK and have that work get performed.  If I wait until the work is complete before sending back a response, the 'client' will have timed out.